# Log4net not working in IIS7 on windows server 2008

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

Logs are not created on the server (Windows 2008) and IIS7.  I had given absolute path as well as relative path.

I had given all rights to the log folder.  I had included network user, IUsr and IIS_IUSRS, and gave permission to every one. also.

It is not writing logs to that folder

the entries on the web config is as follows

```
 <section name="log4net"   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />

 <log4net>
 <logger name="GeneralLogger">
 <level value="ALL" />
 <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
 </logger>
 <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
 <file value="C:\\vhosts\\staging.customerportal.com\\log\\CustomerPortal.log"/>
 <appendToFile value="true"/>
 <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
 <rollingStyle value="Date"/>
 <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
 <acceptOnMatch value="true"/>
 <levelMin value="DEBUG"/>
 <levelMax value="FATAL"/>
 </filter>
 <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
 <conversionPattern value="%-5p %d %5rms %X{addr} %-22.22c{1} %-18.18M - %m%n"/>
 </layout>
 </appender>
 </log4net>
```

I had tried giving single slash and well as double slash in the file value in web config nothing works.

The code in the global.asax.cs is

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
 {
   private static log4net.ILog log =   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

    protected void Application_Start()
    { 
      log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

    }
```

code in assemblyinfo.cs is

```
   [assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="web.config", Watch=true)]
```

I had tried with this code and also without this code in assemblyinfo.cs

It is not working.

Where as When I use absolute path in localhost the logs are written to that folder properly

It fails on the server

I had tried both these options in the controller file

```
  //private static log4net.ILog log =     
        log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType)      ;
   private static log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("GeneralLogger");
```

I had tried a path which does not exists, it did not created folder.

Please help me. Please help me how to enable logs using log4net in server

Comment: This sounds a lot like a permissions problem. Are you 100% sure that the user account the application pool is running under has write access to the log folder?

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your logger before configuring the logmanager (actually you configuring it twice) by calling the Configure on Application_Start.

Option 1:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
private static log4net.ILog log =   log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));

protected void Application_Start()
{ 
  //Remove: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

}
```

And keep:

```
  [assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="web.config", Watch=true)]
```

Option 2:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
private static log4net.ILog log;

protected void Application_Start()
{ 
  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
  log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MvcApplication));
}
```

And remove:

```
//Remove:  [assembly: XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile="web.config", Watch=true)]
```